# Insert/update to sql_ascii encoding postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, encoding, gbk

Here is a postgreSQL with server encoding SQL_ASCII. When I get data, I must use function `convert_to(column1, 'SQL_ASCII')` in select, and then use `new String(value1, 'GBK')` in java to get the right value.

But, when I send data by insert/update, the value in DB always error. Anyone can tell me how to send SQL including Chinese or other character by Java?

Apache DBCP config:

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/fxk_db_sql_ascii
username=test
password=test
initialSize=10
maxTotal=10
maxIdle=10
minIdle=5
maxWaitMillis=1000
removeAbandonedOnMaintenance=true
removeAbandonedOnBorrow=true
removeAbandonedTimeout=1
connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=SQL_ASCII;allowEncodingChanges=true
```

SQL query in java:

```
    String sql = "select user_id, first_name as first_name, convert_to(first_name, 'sql_ascii') as first_name1, last_name as last_name, convert_to(last_name, 'sql_ascii') as last_name1 from public.tbl_users";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> rowData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            rowData.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i)==null?"":new String(rs.getBytes(i),"GBK"));
        }
        list.add(rowData);
    } 
  rs.close();
```

But how should I do while insert/update?

Comment: You start off with "Here is ...", but haven't included any code or representative date ([mcve]). You haven't clearly demonstrated what you may have done to try and solve this problem in the first place. [ask]

Comment: And I use DBCP to connect DB: connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=GBK;allowEncodingChanges=false.....

Comment: @Alex Provide further detail as edits to your Question, not Comments.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: Many thanks for you comment. The PostgreSQL version is 8.2.44,  the driver is offical JDBC driver 8.4-702.jdbc4, the data source is apache commons-dbcp version 1.4

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `SQL_ASCII`

You should be using a server encoding of `UTF8` rather than `SQL_ASCII`.

The documentation is quite clear about this matter, and even includes a warning to not do what you are doing. To quote (emphasis mine):

> The SQL_ASCII setting behaves considerably differently from the other settings. When the server character set is SQL_ASCII, the server interprets byte values 0-127 according to the ASCII standard, while byte values 128-255 are taken as uninterpreted characters. No encoding conversion will be done when the setting is SQL_ASCII. Thus, this setting is not so much a declaration that a specific encoding is in use, as a declaration of ignorance about the encoding. In most cases, **if you are working with any non-ASCII data, it is unwise to use the SQL_ASCII** setting because PostgreSQL will be unable to help you by converting or validating non-ASCII characters.

## Use `UTF8`

Use an encoding of `UTF8`, meaning [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). This can handle the characters for any language including Chinese.

And the `UTF8` encoding allows Postgres to make use of the [new support](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/) for [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) in Postgres 10 and later.

Java also uses [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encoding. Just let your JDBC driver handle the marshaling of text between Java and the database.

Comment: Anyway, many thanks for your answer, but the DB is not under my control....